# Benefits of deploying Keycloak on EC2 vs ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, keycloak, amazon-ecs

I am looking for the pros and cons of deploying Keycloak on ECS vs EC2. Which give me more control and which service is easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference would it be mainly that you are only paying for the usage of the CPU / RAM in ECS, when in EC2 you are paying for the instance 24/7.

For Keycloak in particular you might have to change the configuration of the Database, to make Keycloak point to a service or change the configuration in the database Docker to persist the information in a S3 or elsewhere.
(This is you are using the Keycloak docker compose)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but maybe this helps somebody looking into this topic.

It depends on the decision if you want to install Keycloak in standalone or in cluster mode. For the Cross-Datacenter-Replication mode you need multicast, which is not supported by EC2. There are alternative to it like s3_ping_native, jdbc_ping etc. but you don't find much about running it on AWS EC2. Currently we are looking into this topic, but are very disillusioned. We found multiple old howtos telling you that replication via non multicast is not production ready.